# Find the best traffic route in a city

Tags: dictionary, graph, routes

In my problem I need to find the best traffic route in a city, from a point A to a point E. But in this route I need to visit all points in the city (A, B, C, D, E). What algorithm I need to use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the definition of the [traveling salesman problem](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Otherwise this is a very simple minimization linear programming problem.